# Extract values for more than one attribute node values via XPath expression

Tags: java, xpath

How can I extract value of more than one attribute node via XPath expression?

A sample XML file is:

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        <tag3 id="1">
            <tage4>
                <tage4code code="1">
                    <tag5>
                        <tage4Value Day="14" Month="Oct" Year="2000" />
                    </tag5>
                    <tag5>
                        <tage4Value Month="Oct" Year="2001" />
                    </tag5>
                    <tag5>
                        <tage4Value Year="2002" />
                    </tag5>
                    <tag5>
                        <tage4Value Day="1" Month="Jan" Year="1999" />
                    </tag5>
                    <tag5>
                        <tage4Value Year="1940" />
                    </tag5>
                </tage4code>
            </tage4>
        </tag3>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

So far I have this XPath string:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("concat((/tag1/tag2/tag3[@id=1]/tage4/tage4code[@code=1]/tag5/tage4Value/@Day, '/' , /tag1/tag2/tag3[@id=1]/tage4/tage4code[@code=1]/tag5/tage4Value/@Month, '/', /tag1/tag2/tag3[@id=1]/tage4/tage4code[@code=1]/tag5/tage4Value/@Year)");
                     NodeList combination1 = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                     for (int a = 0; a <= combination1.getLength(); a++) {
                            System.out.println("date : " + combination.item(a).getNodeValue());
                        }
```

My Expected result

14/Oct/2000
Oct/2001
2002
1/Jan/1999
1940

Can someone help to correct my XPathExpression

Comment: Using pure xpath, you can get to `14/Oct/2000
/Oct/2001
//2002
1/Jan/1999
//1940`; you'll obviously have to process the output to remove the redundant `/`. I can post if you think it'll help.

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm fine with that output 14/Oct/2000 /Oct/2001 //2002 1/Jan/1999 //1940

Comment: @JackFleeting you can post the xpath, I'm looking some what same

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm getting javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: concat

Answer (score 1):

**XPath 2.0 solution** :

```
tokenize(replace(replace(replace(substring-after(string-join(//tag5/*|//tag5//@*,","),","),",,","%"),","," ")," ","/"),"%")
```

Output :

```
String='14/Oct/2000'
String='Oct/2001'
String='2002'
String='1/Jan/1999'
String='1940'
```

**XPath 1.0 solution** :

```
concat(translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[1]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[1]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[1]/@Year))," ","/"),"|",translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[2]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[2]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[2]/@Year))," ","/"),"|",translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[3]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[3]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[3]/@Year))," ","/"),"|",translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[4]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[4]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[4]/@Year))," ","/"),"|",translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[5]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[5]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[5]/@Year))," ","/"))
```

Output :

```
String='14/Oct/2000|Oct/2001|2002|1/Jan/1999|1940'
```

Or with new line separator :

```
concat(translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[1]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[1]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[1]/@Year))," ","/"),codepoints-to-string(10),translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[2]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[2]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[2]/@Year))," ","/"),codepoints-to-string(10),translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[3]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[3]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[3]/@Year))," ","/"),codepoints-to-string(10),translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[4]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[4]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[4]/@Year))," ","/"),codepoints-to-string(10),translate(normalize-space(concat((//tage4Value)[5]/@Day," ",(//tage4Value)[5]/@Month," ",(//tage4Value)[5]/@Year))," ","/"))
```

Output :

```
String='14/Oct/2000
Oct/2001
2002
1/Jan/1999
1940'
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath expression

```
//tag3[@id="1"]//tage4code[@code=1]//tag5/tage4Value/concat(@Day,'/',@Month,'/',@Year)
```

should output

```
14/Oct/2000
/Oct/2001
//2002
1/Jan/1999
//1940
```

Comment: I'm getting javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: concat

Comment: @stacktome It's definitely a valid xpath expression and `concat` is supported by XPathExpression. I'll take a look around.

Answer (score 0):

This way we can create a dynamic way of reading the child.

```
xpathExpression = "count(//tag1/tag2/tag3[@id=1]/tage4/tage4code[@code=1]/tag5/tage4Value)";
                double nodeList1 = (double) xpath.compile(xpathExpression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
                int s = (int) (nodeList1);
                for (int z = 1; z <= s; z++) {

                    xpathExpression = "normalize-space(concat((//tag1/tag2/tag3[@id=1]/tage4/tage4code[@code=1]/tag5/tage4Value)["
                            + z
                            + "]/@Day,\" \",(//tag1/tag2/tag3[@id=1]/tage4/tage4code[@code=1]/tag5/tage4Value)["
                            + z
                            + "]/@Month,\" \",(//tag1/tag2/tag3[@id=1]/tage4/tage4code[@code=1]/tag5/tage4Value)["
                            + z + "]/@Year))";
                    String year = (String) xpath.evaluate(xpathExpression, doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
                    System.out.println(year);
                }
```